# C# Dynamic Arrays and its Calculation

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

I have 2 dynamic textboxes which stores users input in the form of an array  Int32[] iA1 = new Int32[3];

and also have a combo box, which has mathematical operator.
My question is how to get the following output when user fills the number of rows and column dynamically at run time and make an appropriate selection from the combo box.
Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcGZx.png)

Comment: Why did you delete most of your question, your question makes no sense now.

Answer (score 1):

```
string output = "";
Int32[] array = new Int32[3] { 25, 4, 1 };

int rows = array[0];
int cols = array[1];
int op = array[2];

for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
    {
        int value = 0;
        string opStr = "";

        if (op == 1) // +
        {
            opStr = "+";
            value = r + c;
        }
        else if (op == 2) // -
        {
            opStr = "-";
            value = r - c;
        }
        else if (op == 3) // *
        {
            opStr = "*";
            value = r * c;
        }
        // ...

        output += string.Format("{0} {1} {2} = {3}\t", r, opStr, c, value);
    }

    output += System.Environment.NewLine;
}

System.Console.Write(output);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(output);

textarea.Text = output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small console app which does what you want:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var firstNumber = 24;
        var secondNumber = 4;
        var op = "+";

        var result = new List<List<string>>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= firstNumber; i++)
        {
            var list = new List<string>();
            for (int j = 0; j < secondNumber; j++)
            {
                list.Add(i.ToString());
                list.Add(op);
                list.Add(j.ToString());
                list.Add("=");
                list.Add((i + j).ToString());                   

            }

            result.Add(list);
        }
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", item));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You need to take the numbers and the operator from your textboxes.